# Displaying the content of two mysql tables together

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to figure out how to display the content of two mysql tables when one table has multiple matching rows, eg. so that the tables below display the results:

**London** - Harry Smith, Oliver Jones, Jack Taylor

**Manchester** - Charlie Williams, Jacob Brown

```
Table One                                 Table two
+-----------------------------+          +----------------------------------+
| id | branchid | store       |          | branchid | firstname | employee  |
+-----------------------------+          +----------------------------------+
| 1  | 1        | London      |          | 1        | Harry     | Smith     |
| 2  | 2        | Manchester  |          | 1        | Oliver    | Jones     |
+-----------------------------+          | 1        | Jack      | Taylor    |
                                         | 2        | Charlie   | Williams  |
                                         | 2        | Jacob     | Brown     |
                                         +----------------------------------+
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level - but MySQL does have a function for this. See GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: Please update your question with how you *want* the results to be displayed.

Comment: @AndriyM - Listing employees under a header of the branch name on a PHP web page would be ideal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP_CONCAT` will do the job, although we first need to `CONCAT` as well to put firstname and lastname together:

```
SELECT b.store, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(e.firstname, ' ', e.employee)) AS Employees
FROM TableOne b INNER JOIN TableTwo e on b.branch = e.branchid
GROUP BY b.store;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c565/1)

### Result:

```
Store       Employees       
London      Harry Smith,Jack Taylor,Oliver Jones
Manchester  Jacob Brown,Charlie Williams`
```